# How to filter items on a Flatlist?

Tags: react-native, native-base

So i have these two arrays, `category: ["All","First","Second"]` and `cards: [
        {
          id: 1,
          icon: require("../../../assets/logo.png"),
          title: 'Title',
          category: 'First',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          icon: require("../../../assets/logo.png"),
          title: 'Second Title',
          category: 'Second',
        }
      ]` and a Picker to select a `category` value

And what i want to do is render a Flatlist that shows items chosen with the Picker. Basically, somewhat of a filter/category.

How could i go about this?

Comment: You can use `keyExtractor` in Flatlist.   example=`keyExtractor={item => item.category}`

Answer (score 0):

you can have a state that stored the current selected `category` and then using the selected category for filtering the `cards`.

e.g.

```js
state = {
  selected: 'All',
  data: cards,
}

setCategory = (newCategory) => {
  const newData = tab === 'All'
    ? cards
    : tab === 'First'
      ? cards.filter(i => i.category === 'First')
      : cards.filter(i => i.category !== 'Second')
  this.setState({ selected: newCategory, data: newData })
}

render() {
 return (
  <FlatList data={data} extraData={selected} />
 )
}
```

This is just one of the solution, there are many ways to handle it.